# Change a Database Properties On SQL Anywhere 9

Tags: sqlanywhere

i need to change the property (Casesnsitve = on To Casesnsitve = oFF ) for a Databse created on SQl Anywhere 9

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the case sensitivity of an existing database. You will have to create a new database (the easiest way is to use the dbinit utility, but don't use the -c switch), and then use the dbunload utility to unload and reload the data into the new database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly ,
 i neet to add that my case is :
i'am using that database with replication .i have 7 branch each one has a srerver which contain one remote user(database) of that databse '
**************
so i need to verify that i'am in the right way or not :
 i must Creat new dadabase  for each remot user or Creat a new database for the main one then extract a new databse for each remot user ?